# Missing content nav-menus.php in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

For some reason the page under Page -> Menus results in the following image. I havent been working (at any time) in any wp-admin files or folders when the problem occurred. 
Deactivating all plugins didn't solve the problem either.
It seems that content or styles aren't being loaded for some reason.

[image: nav-menus.php missing content]

**EDIT**

I've replaced my complete wp-admin folder with that from a newly downloaded WordPress 4.4.2 version (the same version as the original files). Haven't changed any of the theme's (Enfold) options or edited the functions.php from either the child or the parent theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely removed and reinstalled WordPress fixed my problem.